# SQL Database Comparison

Tags: sql, t-sql, comparison, ssms, database-comparison

I have two databases: `DBTarget` and `DBTest`. I've run several custom scripts on `DBTest`, so now `DBTest` and `DBTarget` should be identical in every way (Tables, Values in tables, Columns, SPROCS, etc.)

***Question***: Is there an easy way to compare these two databases?

The only strategy I can think of is:

```
USE [DBTarget];
SELECT * FROM tblTableN;
USE [DBTest];
SELECT * FROM tblTableN;
```

I would have to do this for **each** table, and visually compare them myself. However, this seems very error prone and has a high chance of human error.

Does anyone know of a better way? I'm using TSQL in SQL Management Studio 2005.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few options:

- Use one of [the redgate products](http://www.red-gate.com/products/).
- Write a script to do a full outer join between each of the tables you want to compare, with comparison logic. Include system tables to check your structure etc is the same
- Script/query the database and the data, then do a text comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Try this tool(its freeware):

[DBComparer](http://dbcomparer.com/)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/index.htm for data 
http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm for schema